# Mirror desktop Firefox tab to Chromecast

Tags: gratis, linux, firefox, chromecast

It is easy to display a Google Chrome tab's content on a Chromecast projector.
But how to do with Firefox?

Requirements:

- Display just one tab, not the whole screen
- Free
- Works on Linux (at least Ubuntu)